# How to enable Javascript on Custom Azure AD B2C SignUpOrSignin Policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, policies, azure-ad-b2b

I am trying to enable Javascript on my custom "SignUpOrSignin.xml" policy, so I can take custom actions on the Reset Password and Sign Up buttons.

I did the following steps on SignUpOrSignin.xml :

```
 <RelyingParty>
<DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
<UserJourneyBehaviors>
  <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
</UserJourneyBehaviors>
 .........
 .........
 .........
</RelyingParty>
```

and on TrustFrameworkBase.xml :

```
 <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
    <LoadUri>https://ttt.blob.core.windows.net/b2c-migration-users/pages/unified.html</LoadUri>
    <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
    <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:unifiedssp:1.1.0</DataUri>
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
      <Item Key="TemplateId">azureBlue</Item>
    </Metadata>
  </ContentDefinition>
```

Unfortunetly, when I try to upload the SignUpOrSignin.xml policy in the AAD B2C Instance, I receive the following validation error:

```
Validation failed: 1 validation error(s) found in policy "B2C_1A_JITMIGRAION_SIGNUP_SIGNIN" of tenant "mytenant.onmicrosoft.com". Please use page contract in content definitions when enabling JavaScript.
```

What am I missing ? Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any `ContentDefinition` that you want to enable JS on, the `DataUri` needs to be the contract version. That means `urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:unifiedssp:1.1.0` needs to be changed to `urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:1.2.0` (See [Content Definitions Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions#migrating-to-page-layout)). The page layout version is also different, and you can see what those differences are by going [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout).